# How do I move files from many child directories into my root directory?

Tags: bash, shell, script

I'm using bash on Mac 10.9.5.  I have PDF files in many directories, all one level from the root ...

```
Dir_1/abc.PDF
Dir_2/def.PDF
Dir_3/ghi.PDF
Dir_3/jkl.PDF
...
```

How do I write a shell command to move all these files into the "root" directory, that is make the files line up alongside the child directories ...

```
abc.PDF
def.PDF
ghi.PDF
Dir_1
Dir_2
Dir_3
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just:

```
mv ./*/*.pdf .
```

I've done a test on my computer (zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)) and it worked perfectly:

```
> ls -r *    

sub3:
r.2  r.1

sub2:
s.2  s.1

sub1:
t.2  t.1

> mv ./*/*.pdf .
> ls
r.1  r.2  s.1  s.2  sub1  sub2  sub3  t.1  t.2


> tree                                                            
.
├── r.1
├── r.2
├── s.1
├── s.2
├── sub1
├── sub2
├── sub3
├── t.1
└── t.2
```

Comment: This is what I had intended to write, but did not have enough indenting so the `*` got eaten.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv */*.PDF .
```

That will expand to a list of all files with extension `.PDF` in all subdirectories one level deep, and move those to the current directory.

A complication may arise if there are so many that you get the error `argument list too long`. In that case this will work, assuming there are no special characters like spaces, semicolons, quotes etc. in the directory or file names:

```
echo */*.PDF | xargs -i{} mv {} .
```

`xargs` is made for such situations: it takes strings on its input, collects as many as will go in a single execution, and then run the command given with the collected list. Here we tell `xargs` to replace `{}` with the list.

Comment: Hi, When I enter the echo command, I get a "xargs: illegal option -- i" error.  Note that I'm using bash on Mac 10.9.5 if that matters.

Comment: To best of my knowledge I think `mv /.PDF .` will search in root directory `/` for hidden file (because of `.`) that is named `.PDF`. But, maybe I'm wrong. I have never seen such syntax for mv.

Comment: The  `mv /.PDF .` happened because the formatting ate my `*` characters. I'll edit it now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` for this:

```
find * -name "*.pdf" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} ../ \;
```

- `-name "*.pdf"` means the pattern to match
- `-maxdepth 1` means it will only go one level deep
- `-type f` means ignore everything that's not a file (includes symlinks, directories etc.)
- `-exec mv {} ../ \;` is the command to execute for each file found - to be specific, this means the command is `mv <FILENAME> ../`

Comment: Hi, When I enter your command, I get a "find: *.pdf: No such file or directory" error, even though there are definitely files in those directories with ".pdf" extensions.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't test it so there was an error I missed, the pattern needs to be `*` while .pdf files are matched using `-name` - edited it now.

Comment: You should use `.` as begin point for `find` instead of `*`. If there are very many files in the current directory this will also fail with *argument list too long*.

Comment: What is the difference between using `*` and `.` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I use "Directory Opus" {https://www.gpsoft.com.au/dscripts/download.asp} on windows instead of Explorer to enable searching and imaging.
At the root search for *.*. This will display all files in the root directory.
"Ctrl A" to highlight 'all' then Ctrl shift to remove the  directories from this list.
"Ctrl C" this list which now consists of just the files located in the root.
'Esc' to the source of your root. Return to the root and 'Ctrl V' to past the files directly in the root directory.
The flaw with this system is that the files are duplicated is 2 locations.